# Laravel + stored procedure: Error Packets out of order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure from laravel 5.6, the stored procedure works okay from the database client.

```
CALL storedProcedure1(95, 2);
```

but when I use:

```
$db = DB::select('exec storedProcedure1(?,?)', array(
    $param1,
    $param2
));
```

from laravel I got the following:

> "message": "Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet
>   size=131072",  "exception": "ErrorException",  "file":
>   "D:\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Concerns\ManagesTransactions.php",
>   "line": 202,

What should I do so I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the `config/database.php` file and add this to your database connection

```
'options'   => array(
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
),
```

> Warning: This is probably not the best way to do this.

I found this solution here : [source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/packets-out-of-order-error)

Comment: I just added `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true` to my options array and it worked for me

Comment: Adding _PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES_ to the database config had a **serious side effects**. Floats and decimals were stored as ints (losing their decimal place).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You can solve this packet size issue in laravel 5.4. Writing this lines of code in database file. Write this lines of code where you have issue like if you have issue in MYSQL then write in MYSQL oR PGSQL then in pgsql same do for other database type.

```
'options'  => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', 
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
    ]
```

Comment: The thing is that enabling ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES option, for some reason, starts casting integers into strings on models fetched with Eloquent. So, correct me if I'm wrong but I don't find this being a solution.
Any other workaround is welcomed.

Comment: Adding _PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES_ to the database config had a **serious side effects**. Floats and decimals were stored as ints (losing their decimal place).

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, I only wanted to call a stored procedure at one place in entire app. So, I didn't want to set PDO attributes in Configs to prevent from any anomaly on global level. Thus, I created a PDO connection and achieved it as following:

```
        $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
        $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->query('CALL my_stored_proc()');
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.
But I have a question: Once the procedure is called, must I undo the attribute settings or it lasts only for the current place?

Answer (score 0):

The error is an incompatibility of how php talks to the MySQL server.

Fixes include:

- Avoiding the bug - potentially not using stored procedures (recommended in general IMHO)
- Upgrading the MySQL server version (to something more tested with laravel)